# How to properly structure a method call to requestAuthorizationOfType:, an NSWorkspace method?

Tags: objective-c-blocks

I'm going to re-ask, then clearly answer this question which I feel was improperly deleted. The question involved my first attempt at trying to properly structure a call to the NSAuthorization and NSFileManager and involved blocks which are, in my opinion, very un-Objective-C like, poorly described, and have few code examples. So, here's the answer.

```
[self set_theWorkspace:[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]];
theType = NSWorkspaceAuthorizationTypeReplaceFile;

void (^myCompletionHandler)(NSWorkspaceAuthorization *, NSError *); // declare the completion routine

myCompletionHandler = ^(NSWorkspaceAuthorization *theAuth, NSError *theError) { // perform the auth request
    if (theError == nil) {
        [self set_theFileAuthorization:theAuth]; // save the authorization
        [(NSNotificationCenter*)[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myCompletionHandlerDidComplete" object:nil]; // let your code know the handler completed
    }
};

[theWorkspace requestAuthorizationOfType:theType completionHandler:(void (^)(NSWorkspaceAuthorization *theAuth, NSError *theError))myCompletionHandler]; // execute the request
```

1. I want to get an authorization to replace a file so first declare the type of Auth request I want.
2. Then, inline, you declare the name of your completion handler.
3. Using the completion handler "block", you request the authorization which causes the OS to issue a panel to request the user's password - which you can't see. It may take a while for the user to do that, hence the completion routine.
4. When the completion routine completes, you can then post a notification to your code that completion occurred and you can then proceed along your way to do that file replacement or not depending on if the user let you.

I hope this helps, I was really unfamiliar with blocks, completion routines, and the file manager when I originally asked that question and it took a while for me to puzzle it out. I re-posted the question with an answer in hopes that it helps someone else.

Comment: Please post a question and an answer. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I don't understand these down votes for the question. Or the answer for that matter. There is very little cogent information anywhere on blocks, callbacks, or even use of the file manager. This question combined all three into an answer with working code.

Comment: The question doesn't have an answer, please don't post the answer in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The code is usually structured like

```
[NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace requestAuthorizationOfType:NSWorkspaceAuthorizationTypeReplaceFile
        completionHandler:^(NSWorkspaceAuthorization *theAuth, NSError *theError) {
    if (theError == nil) {
        self.theFileAuthorization = theAuth; // save the authorization
        [NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter postNotificationName:@"myCompletionHandlerDidComplete" object:nil]; // let your code know the handler completed
    }
};
```

Explanation:

```
[self set_theWorkspace:[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]];
```

Camel case is used for names with multiple words, `set_theWorkspace:` should be named `setTheWorkspace:`. In Modern Objective-C the dot syntax is used: `self.theWorkspace = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace;`.
There is one shared `NSWorkspace` object per app and `[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]` always returns the same `NSWorkspace`, no need to store it unless it is used frequently.

```
[(NSNotificationCenter*)[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"myCompletionHandlerDidComplete" object:nil]; // let your code know the handler completed
```

`[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]` returns a `NSNotificationCenter`, no need to typecast.

Warning:

```
self.theFileAuthorization = theAuth;
```

Could create strong reference cycle. See [Avoid Strong Reference Cycles when Capturing self](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW16)

Comment: Ah, I see. A problem I'm having is that I'm very uncomfortable using Objective-C 2.0 and though slowly learning it, have been using Objective-C 1.0 for over 12 years so pretty much know how to do things with it. Not so much with 2.0.